# Expanded usercards for all users

Tags: feature-request, privileges, usability, user-card

I know the expanded usercard is a privilege given to established users. However, it would be much more useful if you could see some basic profile information of *any* user without having to go to their profile page — regardless of how many posts they have. At the moment, all you can see on a usercard is the reputation, name, and badges. There are many cases in which you need some basic information about the person's professional background, nationality, etc. as well mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/05/expanding-user-cards/). Just for instance, I'm an English learner on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and anytime I receive answers or review other posts, I have to go back and forth between the posters' profile pages and their posts to check at least two pieces of information:

1. Where are they from:

   - Are they native speakers?
   - Do they speak American or British English, for example?
2. What do they do:

   - Are they English teachers?
   - Are their jobs somehow related to the English language, like writers or newspaper editors?

It helps me evaluate and understand the posts better.

Having the expanded usercard is considered a *privilege* for some *posters*, but not having it is a *nuisance* to some *readers*. Simply put, it's against the site usability.

Comment: rep requirement is probably there in order to prevent this feature from abuse by all kinds of spammers and trolls

Comment: Only very few users have any of those four details you want in their full profile, so this request is really not feasible. Not worth spending time on something only 0.00001% of the users will have any use for. I mean, where you saw a user who mention he/she is native English speaker or not? Speak American or British English? Being an English teacher? Maybe there are, but only handful few out of millions of users.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: "Not worth spending time on something only 0.00001% of the users will have any use for." Even if that's true, which is debatable, we should consider those few users. What percentage of the Internet users are blind? Very few. However, we always consider them when designing websites.

Comment: That's not a fair comparison @Mori. The information you are looking for is only a click away. To a blind person, however, a website that doesn't follow certain standards may be completely inaccessible.

Comment: If you need this much confirmation a post is worth evaluating based on how someone eats their eggs then you've missed the part where the post is supposed to be judged on its own

Comment: @yannis: You have a point, but the feature I request is _much_ easier to implement than making a website accessible to the blind. It saves some users, including me, from that _single_ click.

Comment: Expanded usercards contain user-submitted information. Right now that information is not easy to moderate. Until it is, the risk of putting that information right under every post the user makes for everyone to see (and crawlers to index) is considerably higher than the benefit of saving a very few people a click. This is what @gnat alluded to in the first comment.

Comment: So, all in all, this isn't a bad request. Just one that can't really work with the current system.

Comment: @random: As an answerer on ELL, the information about whether someone is a native BrE or AmE or AusE or InE speaker could actually be a lot more important than you're giving credit. Especially for amateurs, the existence of specific differences between dialects is often surprising.

Comment: @yannis: Would you mind taking a look at the comments under _A Busy Programmer_'s post? I'm not sure if you're notified.

Answer (score 1):

You have a point; it does sometimes seem like a pain to look someone's profile up.

However, having said that, many of the new users can be trolls (experienced many of them on StackOverflow) who would abuse their profile page by adding all kinds of wacky things just to spam the StackExchange network.

These users have no interest in working their way up to earn the deserved 1k rep for an expanded flashcard; hence, giving them this privelege would be almost like *downgrading* the user that has worked hard enough to gain the rep for an expanded flashcard.

The StackOverflow site clearly specifies that:

> Established users are those who have been participating on the site for a fair amount of time. They gain the following **_privileges**.
>
> - They may view the vote counts on posts
> - **An expanded usercard will show additional profile information**

Another thing: many new users join the community *just* to ask questions; they do not even take the tour to earn the *Informed* badge, much less fill out their profile details. Hence, it would be a wasted of such a feature on them, as most profile cards of new users would be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Both going to a user's profile page and hovering your mouse over their usercard are optional. It's a paradox that we allow spammy profiles, but we can't stand spammy usercards. Expanded usercards are excerpts of profile pages. If we have clean profiles, usercards will be automatically clean. Why do we let new users have extended information on their profiles in the first place? They should be limited to some basic information like a _display name_.

Comment: One more thing: no one can manage Stack Exchange better than its users. We can put a _flag_ to report inappropriate content to moderators on both profiles and expanded usercards. "giving them this privelege would be almost like downgrading the user that has worked hard enough to gain the rep for an expanded flashcard." That's why I think the expanded usercard shouldn't be a privilege. "it would be a wasted of such a feature on them, as most profile cards of new users would be empty." An expanded usercard only works if there are at least 28 characters in the _About Me_ section of your profile.